# Why Apache Tika always use UTC timzone to format create-date of meta data

Tags: apache-tika

I am using Tika to extract meta data of file, I found the the create date Tika extract from file always displays with UTC timezone.

I read source code of org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata (Tika version is 0.9), I found following code snippet:

```
/**
     * The ISO-8601 format string we use for Dates.
     * All dates are represented as UTC
     */
    private static final DateFormat iso8601Format =
        createDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", "UTF");




 /**
     * Returns a ISO 8601 representation of the given date. This method is
     * synchronized to prevent concurrent access to the thread-unsafe date
     * formats.
     *
     * @see <a href="https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-495">TIKA-495</a>
     * @param date given date
     * @return ISO 8601 date string
     */
    private static synchronized String formatDate(Date date) {
        return iso8601Format.format(date);
    }
```

Does anyone know why Tika always use UTC timezone to format a meta create date?

Comment: Because it's a well known format and an international standard? Nothing stopping you changing it into another timezone later if you need it to. What problem are you seeing?

Comment: I want to the create-date extract from meta data is timezone sensitive according to user timezone. For example if user timezone is utc the create-date is 2014-07-16T09:45:45Z, and if user timezone is UTC+8 the create-date should be 2014-07-16T17:45:45Z.

Comment: Don't you mean `2014-07-16T17:45:45+08:00` ? That Z on the end has a special meaning, which tells you it's in UTC. If you want a time in +8, then you need to put that on the end as the timezone instead!

Comment: Yeah, I mean 2014-07-16T17:45:45+08:00, but Tika always give us the time like this "2014-07-16T09:45:45Z", You mentioned put the +8:00 on  the end, so should we put the +8:00 as timezone before Tika extract date or after Tika extract date? If you have a simple code example that would be really helpful

Comment: So why not parse that into a Java Date object, then use normal Java timezone manipulation stuff to switch it from UTC into whatever timezone you want?

Comment: Here is the code snippet of class org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser:

Comment: Sorry please forget the last comment, it is a invalid comment. When Tika extract create date from meta data of a file, it will convert the Date object to string and store it into meta map, so after I get the meta map from Tika I have no chance to get the Date object

Comment: It's a string in a stunningly well known and widely supported format, so you can either parse it back to a date yourself, or ask Tika to based on the appropriate property...